# mismatching gradle dependencies for Mapbox Maps SDK for Android

Tags: java, android, gradle

These are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.1.2')
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation- 
    v7:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
}
```

I am getting the following warning: All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 27.1.1. Examples include com.android.support:animated-ve`enter code here`ctor-drawable:28.0.0 and com.android.support:design:27.1.1 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your targetSdkVersion).

According to the documentation I can use the following line to fix

```
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.1.2'){
exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name'}
```

but i have no idea what group_name and module_name should be? Link to docs is here [enter link description here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/)

please help?

This is the error i get at run time :

> Android resource linking failed
>   C:\Users\tmast\AndroidStudioProjects\GUIPlay\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   C:\Users\tmast\AndroidStudioProjects\GUIPlay\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
>   C:\Users\tmast\AndroidStudioProjects\GUIPlay\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3125: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   C:\Users\tmast\AndroidStudioProjects\GUIPlay\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:3126: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
>   error: failed linking references.